# Prevent multiple radio buttons from being selected in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Code:

```
    <div id="summary_SelectAgent" runat="server">
        <div class="rowClass"><p>Select an Agent:</p></div> 

        <div style="max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
        <p><asp:GridView ID="dgvAgents" runat="server" CellPadding="2" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            Width="100%" BorderStyle="none" GridLines="None" CssClass="columnfield_small SelectAgentTable">
          <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#3C6994" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="left"/>
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20"><ItemTemplate><asp:RadioButton ID="rbtSelectAgent" runat="server" 
              AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="False" GroupName="SelectAgent"/></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cName" HeaderText="Agent Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cAddress" HeaderText="Address" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cCityStZip" HeaderText="City/State/Zip" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nIDNumber" HeaderText="#" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="false"/>
          </Columns>
        </asp:GridView></p>
        </div>
        <div class="rowClass"></div>
    </div>
```

I feel I need to add a JavaScript event to the radiobutton area.

Comment: set same group name for the radioboxes; [GroupName: 
Gets or sets the name of the group that the radio button belongs to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396); like `<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtSelectAgent" runat="server" GroupName="test1" 
              AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="False" GroupName="SelectAgent"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a radio button within a gridview, you have to set the `GroupName` in the `OnInit` event of your radio button.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="test" runat="server" OnInit="test_Init" />
```

Now your code behind

```
protected void test_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton rbtn = (RadioButton)sender;
            rbtn.GroupName = "groupgrid";
        }
```